# flex: 0 0 using new css flexbox

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

In chrome I set an a child element of a `display: flex` element as `flex: 0 0`. I took this to mean no stretching or shrinking, however it shrinks to 0 pixels. Does 0 have a different meaning for `stretch` and `shrink`, or is this a bug in chrome?

**EDIT** Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BPk4Q/

Comment: can you show full code CSS & HTML. flex: defaut is 1 1 auto if i do not mistake. to shrink or expand you can use align-items on parent or align-self on child too .

Comment: For FF auto is missing http://jsfiddle.net/BPk4Q/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `flex: none` (which is a special value that's equivalent to `flex: 0 0 auto`).

The value you're currently using, `flex: 0 0` (without the 'auto'), implies a `flex-basis` of 0%, which indeed tends to make things 0-sized (given that the `flex-grow` value is also 0).  Quoting the flexbox spec about the `flex` shorthand:

> <‘flex-basis’> 
>   [...] When omitted from the flex shorthand, its specified value is 0%.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-property

So, anyway, it sounds like you want `flex: none`.